# Cannot resolve Imports Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, bundle, menuitem

So I was using android studio working on a project and suddenly the following errors started coming in the import section..

```
import android.os.Bundle; //Cannot resolve symbol 'Bundle'
import android.view.Menu; //Cannot resolve symbol 'Menu'
import android.view.MenuItem; //Cannot resolve symbol 'MenuItem'
```

I searched a dozen topics on many forums, many of them suggesting me to reinstall the **SDK**, point to the right android `SDK` in the configurations, I even reinstalled the **IDE**, but the error keeps popping again and again..

Can Anyone Help........??

Comment: At first clean and rebuild your project . Finally close android studio and re open . Please fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Clean project
2. Invalidate cache and restart studio
3. Check android SDK path is proper
4. Check is there any error in any of your resource file

if above doesn't work

#### At last : Restart your PC and Reopen Android Studio

Comment: Thanks... That really helped... :)